# Discord bot is not finding channel by name

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a Discord bot and when it boots up I am having it search through the guilds text-channels and checking for a specific channel name. If I print out the list of channels, it finds all of them although if I try `if channel.name is "general"` it doesn't change the flag to true.

```
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")
    has_channel = False
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            print(channel.name)
            if channel.name is "general":
                has_channel = True
        print(has_channel)
```

This is my code, and this is the output :

```
Bot is ready.
general
streaming-updates
welcome
goodbye
streaming-schedules
False
```

Would you know why it isn't comparing to true on the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `channel.name` is not of type `str`, and thus `is` evaluates to false. Try:

```
if str(channel.name) == "general":
```

Comment: exactly this worked, I even tried ```str(channel.name) is "general":``` but it didn't work. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I had read in some documentation that ```channel.name``` is type ```str``` but I guess not really. Thanks again.