# Bot doesn't check if the channel with a specific name already exists! || Discord.JS V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const {
  EmbedBuilder,
  ChannelType,
} = require("discord.js");

const serverId = "1110927555693924659";
const categoryId = "1114273709084191765";

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.channel.type === ChannelType.DM && !message.author.bot) {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(serverId);
    const category = guild.channels.cache.get(categoryId);

    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
      (channel) =>
        channel.name === message.author.id &&
        channel.parentID === category.id
    );

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#0099ff")
      .setTitle("New Message")
      .setDescription(message.content)
      .setAuthor({
        name: message.author.tag,
        iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
      });

    if (channel) {
      await channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else {
      const channel = await guild.channels.create({
        name: message.author.id,
        type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        parent: category,
      });

      await channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
  }
});
```

I try to log messages that are sent to my bot via DMs to a channel. This code creates a channel with the ID of the user as a name when someone sends a message to my bot's DM and sends the message there as an Embed Message. The bot must search in the `categoryId` if there is a channel with the same User ID as the user who sent the message then the bot must send the new User message there. If the bot doesn't have a channel created with the User's ID then the bot must create a new channel and send the User's message there. The problem is when I send a message a second time it creates a second channel with my ID instead of sending my message in the channel that was previously created! Any answer is accepted.

### My Intents & Partials:

Intents:

```
Guilds
GuildMembers
GuildMessages
MessageContent
DirectMessages
GuildVoiceStates
```

Partials:

```
User
Message
GuildMember
ThreadMember
Channel
```

I already checked both of these articles [1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470132/discord-bot-is-not-finding-channel-by-name) & [2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962679/way-to-check-if-a-channel-exists), but they are outdated and doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: `message.author.id` is already a string, no need to call `.toString()`

Comment: @Elitezen I already know that but sometimes you can also add it and the code will not return any errors at all. Now, can you answer my question?

Comment: It looks like a typo, `channel.parentID` should be `channel.parentId`. The rest looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you @ZsoltMeszaros ! Indeed that was the problem I never saw that!